# Extract only number between commas

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a returned string like this from my code:  `(<C1>, 4.297, %)`
And I am trying to extract only the value 4.297 from this string using gsub command:

```
Fat<-gsub("\\D", "", stringV)
```

However, this extracts not only 4.297 but also the number '1' in C1.
Is there a way to extract only 4.297 from this string, please can you help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
# Your sample character string
ss <- "(<C1>, 4.297, %)";

gsub(".+,\\s*(\\d+\\.\\d+),.+", "\\1", ss)
#[1] "4.297"
```

or

```
gsub(".+,\\s*([0-9\\.]+),.+", "\\1", ss)
```

Convert to numeric with `as.numeric` if necessary.

Comment: Probably better to not count on _exactly one_ blank space, i.e. use `\\s*` instead of `\\s`

Comment: Great thanks. Yes I did have as.numeric in my 'working-around' version of code.

Answer (score 3):

you can use  `as.numeric` convert no number string to `NA`.

```
ss <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(stringV, ',')))
ss[!is.na(ss)]
#[1] 4.297
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `str_extract` to match one or more numeric elements with `.` and is preceded by a word boundary and succeeded by word boundary(`\\b`)

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(stringV, "\\b[0-9.]+\\b"))
#[1] 4.297
```

If there are multiple numbers, use `str_extract_all`

#### data

```
stringV <- "(<C1>, 4.297, %)"
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to treat your vector as a comma-separated-variable, and use `read.csv`

```
df <- read.csv(text = stringV, colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "character"), header = F)
    V1    V2  V3
1 (<C1> 4.297  %)
```

This method is relying on the 'numeric' being in the 'second' position in the vector.

Comment: `colClasses` isn't actually necessary

Comment: @RichScriven - true. I was being extra cautious :)